# When to start using IL over higher languages

Tags: c#, .net, il

After seeing a few open source projects most by the stack exchange team. I've noticed that a few times they just write straight IL code inlined in the c# function.

A perfect example you can see in a [dapper file](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs).

My guess is that the compiler doesn't generate the code that is felt to be the most efficient and sometimes you just need to do it for the compiler.

My curiosity lies in when does the decision to start using the IL emitter over regular old C#?

I know the examples are for stackexchange but I'm gussing other developers have had to make this decision seeing as [Sigil](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Sigil) exists.

Comment: When the going is really, *really* bad. Hopefully you never get there.

Comment: yeah I figure. I'd just love to see the benchmarks that lead to the decision.

Comment: Dapper uses IL because it needs to dynamically generate code for types it won't know about until runtime. You shouldn't use IL for any other circumstance.

Comment: @CoryNelson so your saying is more because C# has to many restrictions and they needed to get around those by entering an untyped level?

Comment: If you're working with types you don't know about beforehand, you can either use reflection which is very slow or you can do code generation to get something closer to native speed.

Comment: One interesting application of writing IL directly is that you can do things that really confuse decompilers.  For example, the verifier requires that the operand stack has a constant consistent depth on every iteration of a while loop -- the .NET languages all guarantee that depth is zero, so decompilers assume that.  With a non-zero depth you can make those decompilers fail spectacularly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.NET IL is so simple compared to actual CPU assembly languages (x86, etc) that there is only one way to do pretty much everything. Meaning, you can't achieve better performance with better IL, because there is no better IL. (Let's assume you don't generate suboptimal IL intentionally, which a debug build does.)

.NET performance depends a lot more on the JIT-ter. Anyway, the whole idea of a high-level language, JIT-ting, GC-ing, etc,. has its performance tolls, so slight optimizations in IL don't matter too much anyway.

So why do people use IL? It's when you generate code (like when you compile an XSLT, a regular expression, or a dynamic proxy). It's a whole lot faster to do in IL than creating a C# code in a string buffer and compiling that, and that's all.

Apart from the ability to generate code on the fly, when IL is a must, I don't believe IL has any other advantages. C# is such a feature rich and fast evolving language, it would be just crazy not using it. Having to work in IL would be a punishment. You can rest assured that C# can be compiled to as good IL as possible.

You can also feel free to use all kinds of the newest C# features. I agree, things like dynamic may not have the best performance, but it's not about performance, it's about modern features which just help you get stuff done. IL doesn't give you that. (Of course, some new features really help performance, like async, but in very different ways than assembly-level optimizations, on a much higher level.)

And by the way, AFAIK you can not embed IL inside a C# file. Apart from generating new code on the fly, you cannot compile IL into your assembly, at least not in Visual Studio, except with certain tricks involving changing assemblies after they've been built from C#.

Comment: I guess by writing straight IL I meant using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to emit IL opCodes.

Comment: And here's a [much simpler method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx) to generate code on the fly.

Comment: Yes, expression trees are very good for LINQ stuff, like compiling dynamic predicates. But for my examples, especially for dynamic proxies, when you have to compile whole classes and assemblies and implement interfaces etc., IL the only option.

Comment: There is one other advantage of CIL: some valid constructs have no C# counterpart. One particular example that was necessary for me at one point is the ability to call a non-direct base method non-virtually (C# pseudo-code: `class A { public virtual void f() { } } class B : A { public override void f() { } } class C : B { public override void f() { A::f(); } }`). There was no way around that by modifying class `B` because that came from a poorly designed third-party library.